Transformation between the canonical basis and the degraded Bell basis
I would like to know if the following results of mine made are correct.
My goal is to express the canonical basis $ \{ |00\rangle , |01\rangle , |10\rangle , |11\rangle  \} $ using a degraded Bell base by a factor of $c \in \mathbb{C}$. That means that the degraded Bell Base looks like this.
\begin{align*}
|\phi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|00\rangle +c|11\rangle )\\
|\phi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|00\rangle -|11\rangle )\\
|\psi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|01\rangle +c|10\rangle )\\
|\psi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|0​1\rangle -|10\rangle )
\end{align*}
In the following we denote $N := \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} $.
Let's find the passage matrix from Bell base to the canonical one.
$$  P_{Bell \to Canonical} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & c^* & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c^* \\
0 & 0 & c & -1 \\
c & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
As $  P_{Canonical \to Bell} =P^{-1}_{Bell \to Canonical}$ we get
$$ P_{Canonical \to Bell} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & c^* \\
c & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & c^* & 0 \\
0 & c & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
Thus, moreover
\begin{align*}
|00\rangle  = N (|\phi^+_c\rangle  + c |\phi^-_c\rangle )\\
|01\rangle  = N (|\psi^+_c\rangle  + c |\psi^-_c\rangle )\\
|10\rangle  = N (c^* |\psi^+_c\rangle  - |\psi^-_c\rangle )\\
|11\rangle  = N (c^* |\phi^+_c\rangle  - |\phi^-_c\rangle )
\end{align*}
Is this correct? This is very important for me to know because I need it for numerics. Thank you in advance for your help.

Yes, looks good to me.

@Lukas indeed it is correct i understood where my computation goes wrong.

I understood why I did not get the correct result.
It's simply because in the book I am reading they just used, at the begining, a lightly different degraded Bell basis. More precisally this one:
\begin{align*}
|\phi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|00\rangle +c|11\rangle )\\
|\phi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c^*|00\rangle -|11\rangle )\\
|\psi^+_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (|01\rangle +c^*|10\rangle )\\
|\psi^-_c\rangle  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|c|^2}} (c|0​1\rangle -|10\rangle )
\end{align*}
And following the same logic as in my question you obtain.
$  P_{Canonical \to Bell} =P^{-1}_{Bell \to Canonical}$ we get
$$ P_{Canonical \to Bell} = N \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & c^* \\
c & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & c & 0 \\
0 & c^* & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
